# How to configure pagination for Team Discussion List in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: discussion-board

I need to configure the pagination to the OOB Team discussion list. I could configured for discussion board but not for the List. What have to do?

Comment: any clue for me ?

Comment: Is anybody know about this topic ?